# How do we round only if the number is with .0 in decimal

Tags: kotlin

Ex 10.0 = 10
10.3 = 10.3
10.7 = 10. 7
Looking for a convenient way from Kotlin Standard library

Comment: Do you mean you want to _format_ the number so that trailing fractional 0s are removed?

Comment: Yes on the similar lines, yes makes sense 10.70 should also be 10.7 or if It is 10.0 then it should be 10

Comment: Are you looking for a multiplatform solution? Or specific to Kotlin/JVM for example? In the former case, I don't think there is any readily available APIs in the standard library.

Comment: As the required output type was String 

This helped `num.toString().replace(".0", "")`

Comment: That wouldn't work for `10.70` though. Can you answer my question? What platform(s) are you targeting?

Comment: Android/ JVM is the platform

Comment: It won't even work for 10.04 = 104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function:

```kotlin
fun removeTrailingZeros(num: String): String {
    if(!num.contains('.')) // Return the original number if it doesn't contain decimal
        return num
    return num
        .dropLastWhile { it == '0' } // Remove trailing zero
        .dropLastWhile { it == '.' } // Remove decimal in case it's the last character in the resultant string
}
```

You can verify the code [here](https://pl.kotl.in/esl3azDif)

Comment: You can also use String.removeSuffix(".") to remove the decimal if it's the last character in the resultant string

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
double number = 23.471;
if (number % 1 != 0)
{
    //round off here
    System.out.print ("Decimal");
}
else
{
    System.out.print ("Integer");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get a string, the easiest way is to work with a string like `num.toString().replace(".0","")`. For numbers conversion does not make sense since the resulting type is different for different inputs.

Comment: If the number is 10.04 the output is 104

Comment: Then you need to use a regular expression instead of a string:
`num.toString().replace("\\.0$".toRegex(),"")`